# VS2019 WinForms no events showing up in Diagnostics Tool

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I've tried to create simple application using WinForms. Using a Designer i added couple buttons textfield etc. No C# code modificiations only drag and drop to Layout. However when running the app no Events are shown on button click or any other action. I'm using VS2019 Professional(Edu licence) Is there a way to fix it?

[image: Events tab remains empty]

**EDIT**
The event listeners and handler are auto generated f.e.:
Form1.cs

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

AND in Form1.Designer.cs

```
this.MultiplyButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button7_Click);
```

Comment: `The event listeners and handler are auto generated:`  ...meaning you double-clicked the button in the designer to generate that stub?

Comment: Yes, when i double clicked the button in the designer it showed me to code listed above in the EDIT (Form1.cs)

Comment: According to this post [Events not collected in diagnostic tools](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/281f549e-5914-4e29-9cf0-4f0ac9dd8d17/events-not-collected-in-diagnostic-tools?forum=vsdebug), it's only collected in the Enterprise edition.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I can do nothing but to upgrade or use console output. If you post it as answer I'll mark it as a solution

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint somewhere? Does the Events section show something at this point?

Comment: No no breakpoints, still no event in events section.
I've only added console output in event listener and console output works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this post [Events not collected in diagnostic tools](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/281f549e-5914-4e29-9cf0-4f0ac9dd8d17/events-not-collected-in-diagnostic-tools?forum=vsdebug), it's only collected in the Enterprise edition.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you added an on-click event listener for that button?
You can do that in the designer or code behind.

Comment: The event listeners are auto generated:
``` private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```